# Is Jayadeva's Gita Govinda a religious text for any sect?

Tags: krishna, sects, radha

It is supposed to be religious:

http://www.ocasopress.com/jayadeva-gita-govinda.html

> WithJayadeva's poem became the focus of a religious sect in India. Buddhism and Hinduism sought to release the enlightened from worldly illusions through renunciation, meditation and physical austerities. Particularly to be avoided was carnal pleasure. In Gita Govinda, however, Krishna embodies the erotic sentiment, and in that sense the cowgirls serve him with rapture and unselfishness. Jayadeva developed the aesthetic experience of love, and the songs typically end with dedications to Krishna, which urge readers to cultivate an appreciation of a taste that is both mental discrimination and physical relish. The two are inseparable, each growing from the other. The poem combines the sweetness of the experiences described, the poetry itself, and the joy that devotees find in relishing Krishna through the text. Indian theologians took this concept of taste further, seeing the lover as someone lifted from the particular into an abstract and universal experience of love, which is the ultimate joy or beatitude, a taste of Brahman itself. The aesthetic experience became a religious one, a state of total absorption in, devotion to and enjoyment of Krishna.

But it has quite explicit depiction of erotic love.

Comment: Gita Govinda is not a scripture but a devotional work dedicated to Krishna.

Comment: There is nothing erotic in Geeta Govind honestly. If u ever read Soundaryalahari it has detail explaination of every ang of Bhagwati devi. And that is not erotic it is pure love and devotion it is ecstasy dripping from the bhakta as he mentions the deity and try to help other sadhakas 'think' and contemplate on the deity n his leelas. Because ppl like us can't neither see prabhu nor his leelas.

Answer (score 1):

Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, the founder of the Gaudiya Vaishnavism, loved to listen to Gita-Govinda written by Jayadeva Goswami. Bhaktivinod Thakur (Srila Prabhupada's Paramguru), one of the acharyas in Gaudiya Vaishnavism, also admitted its importance. In Gaudiya Vaishnavism websites, you will find Jayadeva Goswami's book, biography etc. So it is indeed religious text in Gaudiya Vaishnavism.

References:

1. https://iskcondesiretree.com/page/sri-jayadeva-gosvami
2. https://gaudiyahistory.iskcondesiretree.com/sri-jayadeva-goswami/

Comment: Anything written by Gaudiya Mutt or pre-ISKCON Gaudiya teachers about this? @amritendumukhopadhyay

Comment: For me to accept the answer - I'd like to see a credentialed Gaudiya teacher explicitly declare Gita Govinda to be scripture or otherwise validate it from a religious standpoint @amritendumukhopadhyay .  I don't want to be difficult - I'd like to see something more authoritative, if you don't mind.